# user posting the question and then commenting an answer with another username

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, user-accounts

Strange thing occurred to me right now, please have a look at this question:

[flash components and resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516501/flash-components-and-resizing/9517342#comment12054107_9517342)

A user posted a comment after my answer. By his comment it looks like he is the author of the original question, but the user name is different.

Does he have a double account?

Comment: Do you smell that? Smells like used socks...

Comment: @Bobby what do you mean?

Comment: A [sock puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) is a user that has more than one account.  He can use that account to circumvent blocks and to vote for himself/herself...etc... all-in-all bad behavior and a bad idea.  You should flag the original post for moderator attention and explain the issue in the flag.

Comment: ok, is there a simple way to compare the two user's activity to see if one is voting and/or accepting other's aswers? this could be a nice feature in SE, compare two or more user activities (if not already done under the hoods).

Comment: No, no-one can see who has voted for what and for who - the moderators can take care of this for us.  With a couple of flags on the post it should be dealt with swiftly and professionally by our very capable diamond mods.

Comment: Looks like they screwed up and forgot which one they were logged in as. :)

Comment: @CoffeeRain: identity crisis, that's how it is called :)

Answer (score 13):

So far, I've identified the following users as either socks or part of a votering:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126160/user1126160
https://stackoverflow.com/users/900754/micro
https://stackoverflow.com/users/993437/mercy
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164579/user1164579
https://stackoverflow.com/users/988905/leema-rose
https://stackoverflow.com/users/996753/priya

They all share the same IP, in Chennai.  The IP is notable for the fact that it has seen 13 different users named Anny with <= 6 rep.

I'd say [mercy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993437/mercy) has gained the most benefit from all of these users.

According to Nick Craver, there is action on the dev side for tracking and punishing suspected puppeteers.

Comment: do you have special powers!?

Comment: @vulkanino: I have the power of awesomeness and handsomitude.  Yes.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you suspect it too but don't want to act on it because of uncertainty?

Comment: @Lix - we're not banning sock puppets at the moment, we're letting them do as they please so we have as many test cases as possible for some mod tools we're working on.  They'll be taken care of when we're done using *them*, I promise.

Comment: @Nick - thanks for that clarification.  Its splendid that so much information about features that are in the works are open for the community to learn about and discuss.  [Suspend ALL the sock pups!](http://birdsongmag.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/sock_puppet_2_small.jpg)

Comment: @Nick Craver: Oops.

Comment: Unrelated to anything, there's a new open spot on the moderator team!

Comment: @JNK: Huh?  I don't get it.

Comment: @Won't - there is 1 less unicorn now that SOMEONE broke up a sockpuppet ring before a Valued Associate could data mine and test.

Comment: @JNK: Oh, gotcha.  Well, I guess its unicorn stew for dinner tonight.